# How is a local network device adding a DNS entry

Tags: networking, router, dns

I have a TPLink WiFi extender and noted something interesting about it.

Part of the setup processes tells you to visit tplinkrepeater.net in a browser. If you type this into a normal browser it will display a generic page about how to set it up. However, if the device in questions is connected to the local network, you will instead be directed to the admin page of the device. Using wireshark I was able to determine a DNS query is sent from my computer to my router, which, when the device is on the local network, will resolve the local IP of the device, instead of tplinks server IP which displays the generic page if it can't find one locally.

How is my router resolving tplinkrepeater.net to be the current local IP of the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is your router is not resolving it, as you only are redirected to the admin page of the extender, if you are connected directly to the wifi the extender sends. If you are connected to your router, via wifi or ethernet, it displays the generic setup instructions you mentioned above. Or at least mine is.

What really happens when you open the webpage while being connected directly to the extender is that as all traffic goes through it, it can intercept the DNS queries and redirects `http://tplinkrepeater.net` to itself.

Comment: That makes sense. I was confused at why the router was responding but I understand now. Thanks

Comment: Actuall, the router does resolve it. However, the DNS server inside that router holds a static entry pointing to its own IP address. I'd also argue that DNS queries are not actually intercepted, but the router just advertises itself as the primary DNS server using DHCP. Of course one could make the argument that this is still a form of interception, though.

Comment: @jvda That is not entirely correct. If you are directly connected to your router instead of to your range extender, you are sent to a "real" website on the internet, not to the admin page of the extender. Thus, the DNS server inside your router does not resolve the domain to the ip address of your extender but to the one of the website.